# What's the origin of the phrase 'butter her up'?

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin

What's the origin of 'Butter her up', i.e. to make her more amenable to my intentions?

I think that the origin is plainly related to sex.  We never use this term in relation to men, do we?

Maybe this was/is a term used by ordinary people.  The vulgar sexual meaning might be the reason that no author ever has - to my knowledge - clearly explained it.

This seems, to me, to be the most obvious meaning and origin.  Any counter-suggestions or comments?

Comment: Actually most sources refer to an old Indian religious custom rather than something related to sex:  *an ancient Indian custom of "throwing butterballs of ghee (clarified butter commonly used in Indian cooking) at the statues of the gods" to seek favor. Additionally, the Tibetan tradition of creating butter sculptures for the New Year "can be traced to the Tang Dynasty and the belief that such offerings would bring peace and happiness for the full lunar year*

Comment: *"Butter wouldn't melt in her mouth"* means she's is inhumanly cold.

Comment: *I think origin is plainly related to sex.* which may say more about your thinking process than about the term.

Comment: Thanks for your above misandrist comment Spagirl, but it doesn't further our understanding about the origin of this interesting phrase in any way!

Comment: It's a comment on the question itself which springs from a basic premise which you have not supported. Questions should explain what research the asker has carried out themself, if all you've done is assume and think, my comment is justified. If you've done more than that you need to include it in the question. I'm blowed if i can see where you get misandry in my comment.

Comment: Regarding "I think origin is plainly related to sex." - this is not how this site works.  You should provide citations for your premise and answer should do the same, otherwise this would be a site for opinions.

Answer (score 12):

> We never use this term in relation to men, do we?

Yes, we do:

> *A: Who’s your professor this semester?
>
> B: Professor Ornstein.
>
> A: Oh,
> he’s really tough. If you want to get a good mark, you’d better start
> buttering him up!
>
> B: How should I do that?
>
> A: Start by telling him that
> he is the best professor you’ve ever had. Then keep going….*

http://www.idiomeanings.com/butter-up/

> *My coworker, hoping for a raise, is always buttering up the boss.
>
> If we butter up the bartender, maybe he'll buy us a drink.*

[from The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/butter+up)

> *If you butter up Dad, he'll let you borrow the car.*

This last one, [quoted from The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/butter+up), not only puts an end to your theory, it also adds an explanation:

> This term transfers the oily, unctuous quality of butter to lavish
> praise. [c. 1700]

---

cf. *[grease the wheels](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grease+the+wheels)*

Comment: The question contains a wrong assumption, but it's really asking for the _origin_.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the origin of ‘butter someone up’ is *plainly* related to ‘sex’. According to [TheIdioms](https://www.theidioms.com/butter-up/), *butter someone up* has been derived directly from ‘the act of buttering (spreading butter on) a toast of bread to make it softer and tastier so that the person eating it gets more satisfaction from it’. That site further says that this phrase ‘came to represent spreading nice things about someone [flattering] just so you could get something in return’.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/butter--up) says that *butter up* ‘transfers the oily, unctuous quality of butter to lavish praise’.

[Phrases.com](https://www.phrases.com/phrase/butter-someone-up_44526) also agrees with the above explanation:

> When we butter up the slice of bread, we actually make it more delicious. Similarly, when we need a favor and support of someone, we often praise or flatter him/her

[Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/14-expressions-with-crazy-origins-that-you-would-never-have-guessed/) associates its origin with an ancient religious act in India, it says that ‘The devout would throw butter balls at the statues of their gods to seek favor and forgiveness’, though it doesn't sound plausible to me.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, *butter someone up* has no sexual backstory.

Secondly, *butter someone up* does not come from an Indian religious custom where people throw balls of butter at deities, because, well, there was never any such ritual. It's an urban myth.

##### So, where might it actually come from?

What's interesting is that early instances of it show it used as a non-phrasal verb; in other words, there was no *up*.

Here's a pretty long quote, but I think it's worth our time:

> He will there see that Sir James took the chair at the Fox Dinner in Edinburgh, and was buttered by Mr Cranstoun for the Vindicia Gallicethat Sir James, in return, buttered Mr Cranstoun, declaring the speech in his own laudation to be "one of the most beautiful speeches that ever fell from human lips." He will there see, that Mr Jeffrey ("the delight," as Sir James expressed it, " equally of his hearers and readers,") buttered himself, sung palinode, and toasted RADICAL REFORM like a man. He will there see that Mr Abercrombie buttered Mr John Clerk; and that Mr Cockburn buttered Joseph Hume; and that Mr L. Horner buttered Mr James Gibson; and that Sir J. Mackintosh buttered Lord Johnny Russel; and that Mr John A. Murray buttered the Lord Rosslynn; and that the Lord Glenorchy buttered Sir Ronald Fergusson; and that Mr R. Hunter buttered Mr Henry Brougham; and that Mr P. Brown buttered Lord Archibald Hamilton; and that Mr Cranstoun buttered Earl Grey; and that Major Hay buttered Lord Lansdown; and that Dr Thomson buttered Dugald Stewart; and that Sir Ronald Fergusson buttered Rothiemurchus ; and that they all buttered each other, and abused all the world besides, until one in the morning! [aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh]

That was from [an 1823 issue of *Blackwood's Edinburgh Magazine*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Blackwood_s_Edinburgh_Magazine/BPE7AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA99&printsec=frontcover), and in the midst of that long, jumbly paragraph, notice that there's not a single *up*.

Moving on, let's look at *[The life of John Buncle, Esq](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_life_of_John_Buncle_Esq/ThsGAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA195&printsec=frontcover)*, a 1766 novel about some fictional dude:

> In short, I so **buttered him with words**, and filled him with fowl and wine, that he seemed well pleased, especially when he found there was nothing to pay, as I informed him it was my own dinner I had bespoke, and dined with double pleasure in having the satisfaction of his most agreeable company.

Let's also look at this little ditty, found in [this 1879 book of Irish verses](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Green_Leaves/VX5KAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA49&printsec=frontcover&bksoutput=text), but the poems contained inside may date to an earlier time:

> De Lesseps went to England
> When his grand work was done;
> Great Englishmen to greet him
> Came forward at a run.
>
> They praised him up in speeches,
> They puffed him up in rhymes,
> **They buttered him at banquets**,
> They soaped him in the Times.
>
> “A toast for great De Lesseps,"
> Said England's bland premier ;
> “A medal for De Lesseps,
> Said England's royal heir ;
> High honours for De Lesseps,"
> Said learned men in gowns ;
> ‘Addresses for De Lesseps,
> Said mayors of many towns.

What this suggests is that *to butter* was once a verb with the meaning of *to flatter*, and I found a dictionary entry from 1737 that goes in that direction.

From *[The Universal Etymological English Dictionary](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Universal_Etymological_English_Dicti/uayUU1jWRQ4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PT232&printsec=frontcover)*,

> *to butter*, signifies also, to cheat or defraud in a smooth or plausible manner:
> *He'll not be Buttered; He's aware of your Design, He's upon his Guard*

That meaning isn't *too* far from the sense we're looking for. I was able to find another early use of *butter* that suggests this meaning. The following appears in *[The Crown & Glory of Christianity](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Crown_Glory_of_Christianity_Or_Holin/rrFkAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20butter%22%20flatter%20-up&pg=PA287&printsec=frontcover&bksoutput=text)* (1662) after a translation of a Hebrew line:

> The Hebrew word (*Machalik* from *Chalak*) that is here rendered flatterer, signifies a smooth-boots, a soft **butter-spoken** man, because flatterers, the better to deceive, do use to oyl their tongues, and to **butter their lips**, that fo by their smooth soft speeches they may the more insinuate themselves into men's affections, and to make way for their destruction: flatterers have their silken nets to ensnare and entangle poor souls to their eternal ruine. [:(]

##### tl;dr

The origin of this phrase *probably* lies in a now-archaic meaning of the verb *to butter* which meant something along the lines of 'smoothly deceive'. Later, the *up* portion was added and this was made into an idiomatic phrasal verb.